# Octobercms disble fields in relation

Tags: field, octobercms, mode

I want to disable form fields in the update context, see the image:

[image: disble fields in relation]

I tried this, but it did not work

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
{
    if($context == 'update') {
        $fields->books->disabled = true;
        $fields->user->disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you put this method ? and share your `fields.yaml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are trying to make `relation manager field` **disable(read only)**

But I am sure they are **not** following `same pattern as normal widgets do`.

they can not be disabled directly like that as I **found another easy way**.

you may have used `partial for rendering this relational field` **( book | user )** and your partial `_books.htm` is looking like this.

```
<?= $this->relationRender('comments', ['readOnly' => false]) ?>
```

> You need to **change** it with this one

```
<?php if($this->widget->form->context == 'update'): ?>
    <?= $this->relationRender('comments', ['readOnly' => true]) ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $this->relationRender('comments', ['readOnly' => false]) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The **magic config value** is this `readOnly` property it will make list `read-only or active working`.

try this it will work , if not please comment.

Comment: Hi,a follow-up question in this regard: how would one disable a single field in the relation pop-up? My goal is to set a dropdown in the relation pop-up to the ID of the parent model and to disable it. Any idea's?

Comment: may be you can just use partial for that if you want to show proper information, just use html mark up there no any control it will look better.

Comment: Hi Hardik, thank you. I removed the fields from my fields.yaml file as recommended. I think this is a better solution, indeed. Thanks for your advice!